# Keep aiohttp session alive

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to visit a website every X seconds with parallel and separate sessions, then analyse what is in the response to see if each session should continue or not. However, once the code reaches the second loop it fails.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import logging
import time

interval = 30
instances = 2
visit_url = 'http://www.example.org'

tasks = []

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(message)s',  # Log in format time.milliseconds {message}
    level=logging.INFO,  # Use with logging.info()
    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')  # Display time as Hours:Minutes:Seconds


class StopException(Exception):
    pass


async def quit_app(session, task_, reason):
    logging.info("[{}] {}.".format(task_, reason))
    session.cookies.clear()  # Reset cookies
    session.headers.clear()  # Reset headers
    session.close()  # End HTTP connection
    raise StopException


async def get_status(response):
    if "abow" in response:
        return "success"
    elif "odoap" or "daoscp" in response:
        return "waiting"
    elif "nullt" in response:
        return "fail"
    elif "issue" in response:
        return "banned"
    elif "pending" in response:
        return "pending"
    else:
        return "pending"


async def initialise(headers):
    session = ClientSession()
    task_ = len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()) - instances - 1
    passed = False
    while passed is False:
        async with session as session:
            async with session.get(visit_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True) as initial:
                status = await get_status(await initial.text())  # Check HTML for status
                if status == "success":
                    logging.info("[{}] {}.".format(task_, "Success"))
                    passed = True
                elif status == "pending":
                    logging.info("[{}] {}.".format(task_, "Pending.."))
                    await asyncio.sleep(interval)
                elif status == "waiting":
                    logging.info("[{}] {}.".format(task_, "Waiting..."))
                    await asyncio.sleep(interval)
                elif status == "banned":
                    await quit_app(initial, task_, "Banned")
                elif status == "fail":
                    await quit_app(initial, task_, "Failed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'upgrade-insecure-asks': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
    }  # Add appropriate headers
    start = time.clock()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(instances):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(initialise(headers))
        tasks.append(task)
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    end = time.clock()
    print("Process took {0:.4f} seconds.".format(end - start))
```

This code returns the following error:

> 13:56:58.604 Task exception was never retrieved
>   future: Task finished coro= initialise() done, defined at
>   C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/tests/src/aiohttp_main.py:49
>   exception=RuntimeError('Session is closed',)
>   RuntimeError: Session is closed

I just can't work out how to make the sessions stay alive until I .close() them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just can't work out how to make the sessions stay alive until I .close() them...

The `async with` is a request to close the session. Which means that after you write:

```
async with session as session:
```

...you can no longer use `session` once the body of `async with` is done executing. This is not specific to aiohttp, it's how `with` works in Python. For example, when working with files, `with` is a request to close the file:

```
with open('data.csv') as fileobj:
    # ... read stuff from fileobj

# outside the "with" block, fileobj is closed and you
# can no longer read from it
```

The fix is simple enough, just move the `with` outside the `while` loop. For example:

```
async def initialise(headers):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        # the rest of the code, including the `while` loop, here
```

On an unrelated note, you probably want to replace `len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())` with a global counter of your own. Using `Task.all_tasks()` in this way can start producing incorrect results if you later incorporate other unrelated tasks into the event loop (or a third-party library does that for you).

Comment: Btw, sorry to ask a question in a comment but do you happen to know how to close a session and then stop the code from running (only that session/thread, the rest should keep going)? That is what I'm trying to do with quit_app but it still crashes.

Comment: I think I need a

    try:
        ...
    except StopException:
        pass

somewhere

Comment: @JP Look into [`Task.cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel).

Comment: I don't understand the docs, I don't have a task for each session so it makes no sense. But anyway, it stops itself when there is no more code to run, and what I mentioned before should do that. If I raise StopException within a function that has a `try: <function> except StopException: pass` then that will work. However, I can't work out where to put the try ... except ...

Comment: I think I worked it out, just added a run() function that had a `try: await initialise() except StopException: pass`.

Comment: @JP I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I was assuming "then stop the code from running" means that you have some monitoring coroutine that decides to close a session and stop the code that services it. In asyncio one stops a running coroutine with `Task.cancel`. You can easily have a task per session by creating a task from `initialise`. You already have a list of tasks - you could also have a dict mapping a session to a task, and then issue `tasks[session].cancel()` right after `session.close()`

Comment: I never knew this about the `(async) with` statement, this helped me a lot! For the sake of completeness, the behaviour of asynchronous with is documented in [PEP-492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with). Calling `async with` on the ClientSession object triggers its __aexit__() method afterwards, which executes `await self._close()` which can be retrieved in the [aiohttp source code](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/7cf5785f5383ee67756d0f8d86ea3516b823b940/aiohttp/client.py#L820).